# How to make second Pinia plugin wait for first one?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I am creating a Vue app using Pinia as a state manager. Now I've written a plugin which does my authentication and then saved the token to the state. The second plugin is written to set up my API instance. The second one is dependent on the token of the first one.

When I check the execution order, the second plugin is executed as soon as the first one is waiting for the token to be returned. Is there a way to change this? Both plugins are async functions.

Below is my authentication plugin:

```
export async function authenticationPlugin({ store }: PiniaPluginContext) {
  console.log('starting authentication');
  const msalInstance = store.msalInstance as PublicClientApplication;

  try {
    console.log('starting await for silent sso')
    const { idToken } = await msalInstance.ssoSilent(store.msalRequest);
    console.log('signed in using silent sso and fetched id token');
    const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];
    msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
    console.log('active account set');
    store.idToken = idToken;
    console.log('id token stored in store');
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
      const { idToken } = await store.msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(store.msalRequest);
      store.idToken = idToken;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my API plugin:

```
export async function apiPlugin({ store }: PiniaPluginContext) {
  console.log('starting  api plugin');
  const msalInstance = store.msalInstance as PublicClientApplication;

  console.log('setting up subscription');
  store.$subscribe((mutation, store) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (mutation.events.key === 'idToken') {
      console.log('inside subscription');
      store.api = new Api(new Configuration({
        basePath: config.BASE_PATH,
        // @ts-ignore
        accessToken: mutation.events.newValue
      }));
      console.log('end of subscription');
    }
  });

  const api = new Api(new Configuration({
    basePath: config.BASE_PATH,
    accessToken: store.idToken
  }));

  console.log('api instance made');

  // @ts-ignore
  api.axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(store.msalRequest);

    if (tokenResponse.expiresOn!.getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
      console.log('expire?');
      await msalInstance.ssoSilent(store.msalRequest);
      const { idToken } = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(store.msalRequest);

      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${idToken}`;
    }

    return config;
  });

  console.log('interceptor set');

  store.api = api;

  console.log('api added to store');
}
```

So when the component that uses the API to make a call gets rendered, the token hasn't been set in the API instance for some reason. When I check the store it does have the idToken populated with a token.

Does anyone know how I should proceed here?

Comment: What is "Api"? You probably shouldn't create it eagerly, or make it able to accept a new token because this can happen during the app lifespan. You're recreating `store.api` on token change but not api.axios.interceptor, can be a problem. " the token hasn't been set in the API instance for some reason" - this needs to be checked in the first place. Generally you shouldn't do anything that relies on auth before it's completed

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I did it the right way, but I was able to solve my case.

So I have two plugins instantiated. The first one is making a call for a token which then is stored in the store. Only when that token is available should the second plugin start.

I added the following to the second plugin:

```
export async function apiPlugin({ store }: PiniaPluginContext) {
 store.$subscribe(({ events }, store) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  if(events.key === "token") {
   // execute your second plugin
  }
 })
}
```

Might be a better way to do this, but this is how I managed.